# NSData is NULL although length is positive

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

Retrieving response data from a webserver I do the following using `NSURLConnection`:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"%@    %i", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], data.length);
    [responseData appendData:data];
}
```

This is giving me:

> (null)    212

In Other projects I did, I did not have such an issue.

This project started about three years ago with the iOS-SDK 3.0 and went since then through 4.x and 5.x.

Comment: the `NSData` is definitely not `nil` the only one `nil` value is provided by `NSString` which is a different object.

Answer (score 4):

This is easy, your data is probably not a valid UTF-8 string. That means that `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` fails and returns `nil`. However `data.length` is still positive because data is there.

Comment: This is really starting to get very strange. I am actually experiencing other problems regarding encoding with this project. PLEASE take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315672/ios-special-characters-strange-issue#comment16527075_12315672

Comment: maybe try logging like this... NSLog(@"my Data: %.*s", [data length], [data bytes]); if parent is correct your content should be there

Comment: @user1423640 The problem is trivial - your data is incorrectly encoded. Log the contents of the `NSData` instance and find the place where the data is corrupted.